# Is there a speed difference in using an array, struct or class?

Tags: c++, performance

I need to do calculations based on a variable anmount of data, each *item* in the data containing 3 values. I could use an *array*, *struct* or a *class* to represent one of the items.

Is there any difference in speed or do they behave all the same way?

```
// #1: Only arrays
typedef int triple[3];

// #2: Using a struct
struct triple {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

// #3: Using a class
class triple {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Comment: Why not get it working first in a way that's intuitive to you? Who cares how fast an incomplete program is?

Comment: Don't worry about the wrong stuff. First get it working. Then profile or *[random pause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)* to see what you need to be concerned about, if anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Structs and classes are the same as far as that goes. As long as you use a constant index, all the math is done at compile time, so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: What do you mean with *As long as you use a constant index*?

Comment: triple[0] should be the same as tripple.a. triple[i] would require a little bit of runtime math (a very little ...)

Comment: I see, thanks, that is something I did not think about. :) Even it might not be very significant.

Answer (score 1):

There should be definitely no difference between `struct` and `class` with `public:` at the beginning and I suspect there will be no difference with array as well. Not at run time.